How can I install cocoapods without getting an error?
I successfully installed latest version of Ruby 3.3.1:
Successfully installed ruby 3.3.1 into /Users/sampleUser/.rubies/ruby-3.3.1

But I am still getting the following error when I try to install cocoapods:
sampleUser/folder % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.7. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.7` and then running the current command again
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

Active install support cannot be installed either. How to fix this? This is done on an Apple silicon computer.

Don't install gems via sudo, ever. You already seem to be running a Ruby version manager. Chances are that the installed Ruby version (3.3.1) isn't used (you can check via ruby -v). Consult your version manager's docs on how to select a Ruby version. Once set, install cocoapods without sudo. If you have multiple dependencies, consider using Bundler to define them within a Gemfile.

Side note, you can use HomeBrew to install Cocoapods also. It's not a solution to fix your issue, it's an alternative solution. Why activesupport can't be installed? Is there an error?
